# KMPlayer adds a light filter on videos

Tags: vlc-media-player, color-profiles, kmplayer

As you can see in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXZsk.jpg), KMPlayer changes my video by making the colors look brighter. VLC on the right, has no problem accurately displaying the colors.

I already tried resetting all the settings, and then reinstalling KMPlayer but this problem seems to persist.

I am clearly no expert in this field but I'm guessing KMPlayer is defaulting to an inaccurate color profile in the system. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I am faced with the same problem and found out that the reason is in default quality/perfomance settings in KMPlayer.

Screenshot - installer's chosen quality option by default:

[image]

I don't know why, but "General (Normal) preset" makes video brighter.

So, to fix the problem we just need to choose option "Quality (3Ghz)":
**Menu -> Video (Advanced) -> Preset: Quality (3Ghz)**

Screenshot - how to find option "Quality (3Ghz)":

[image]